# Fizz Buzz Bizz Fuzz in Java

Tags: java, programming-challenge, fizzbuzz

This questions is originally from http://contestcoding.wordpress.com/2013/06/28/fizz-buzz-bizz-fuzz/.

> - Print the integers from 1 to 100,
> - but for the multiples of 3, print "Fizz" instead and
> - for multiples of 5, print "Buzz".
> - If the number contains a 3 (for example 23), print "Bizz" and
> - if the number contains a 5, print “Fuzz”
> - (if it contains multiple 3s or 5s, just print one "Bizz" or "Fuzz").
> - If the number contains more than one of these attributes, print every word (for example 33 prints "FizzBizz", as 33 is both a multiple
>     of 3 and contains the digit 3).

My Java solution is:

```
public class FizzBuzz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
            // Set this to true when one of the special conditions is met.
            boolean printed = false; 

            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                // When i is divisible by 3, then print "Fizz"
                printed = true;
                System.out.print("Fizz");
            } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                // When i is not divisible by 3 but is divisible by 5, then print "Buzz"
                printed = true;
                System.out.print("Buzz");
            }

            if (Integer.valueOf(i).toString().indexOf("3") != -1) {
                // When i has the digit 3 in it, then print "Bizz"
                printed = true;
                System.out.print("Bizz");
            } else if (Integer.valueOf(i).toString().indexOf("5") != -1) {
                // When i has the digit 5 in it, then print "Fuzz"
                printed = true;
                System.out.print("Fuzz");
            }

            if (printed == false) {
                // The number does not satisfy any of the special conditions above.
                System.out.print(i);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Please provide code review comments.

Comment: Wouldn't it simply make the most sense to have an acceptance test in place before just jumping right to code?  As with the original fizz buzz, you should be able to know exactly what all of the lines of the output should be in advance, and then craft your program to match that test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overall, this is a pretty straightforward program. See the bottom of my answer for an ***[Extreme Makeover: Code Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_Makeover:_Home_Edition)*** of the program.

---

[You have a hard-coded "magic number" in your `for` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad).  It would be better to use a variable.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++) // not the best

int num = 101;
for (int i = 1; i < num; i++); // better
```

---

Your `if` test conditions can be shortened a bit.

```
if (Integer.toString(i).indexOf("3") != -1)
```

---

Your logic is a bit off.  You should actually have fewer `else if` conditions (this is rarely the case, but here it is applicable).  For example, when `i` reaches "15", is should print "FizzBuzzFuzz", but your program only prints "FizzFuzz".

---

### Final code:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        int num = 101;
        for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)
        {
            boolean printed = false;

            if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                printed = true;
                System.out.print("Fizz");
            }
            if (i % 5 == 0)
            {
                printed = true;
                System.out.print("Buzz");
            }

            if (Integer.toString(i).indexOf("3") != -1)
            {
                printed = true;
                System.out.print("Bizz");
            }
            if (Integer.toString(i).indexOf("5") != -1)
            {
                printed = true;
                System.out.print("Fuzz");
            }

            if (printed == false) System.out.print(i);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

---

### ***Extreme Makeover: Code Edition***

Let's use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) <strike>and some [ternary operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?:)</strike>.  And let's get rid of that `boolean`.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        int num = 101;
        for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if(i % 3 == 0) sb.append("Fizz");
            if(i % 5 == 0) sb.append("Buzz");

            if(Integer.toString(i).indexOf("3") != -1) sb.append("Bizz");
            if(Integer.toString(i).indexOf("5") != -1) sb.append("Fuzz");

            if (sb.length() == 0) System.out.print(i);
            else System.out.print(sb);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you read the instructions OP gave again, the answer should be `FizzFuzz`

Comment: @syb0rg, I think that I may have read it incorrectly.

Comment: Why use a ternary operator instead of just a single-line if statement: `if (Integer.toString(i).IndexOf("3") != -1) sb.Append("Bizz");` Unless Java's StringBuilder works different from what I'd expect, the return value is just for fluent chaining, but you don't have to assign it.

Comment: Just remember that fancy is usually not what you want with code. In this case it has to evaluate all those `sb.Append("")` statements which effectively does nothing, but costs something.

Answer (score 4):

1. Your implementation is broken, for example 15 should print `FizzBuzzFuzz` but yours will print `FizzFuzz`. 35 should print `BuzzBizzFuzz` but yours will print `BuzzBizz`.
2. Turning an integer into a string can be done with `Integer.toString(i)`.
3. For reusability your code should be encapsulated in a class which you can instantiate and play as many games as you like.
4. Once you have refactored the code into a class consider decoupling logic from output. For example you can pass in an [`Appendable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Appendable.html) to which you can append your output without having to care where it ends up.

Comment: Hi ChrisWue, Based on my understanding of the question: The first two conditions (divisibility rules) are mutually exclusive of each other. Similarly, the next two conditions (presence of 3 and 5 in the number) are mutually exclusive. I can see that the question can be read so too. However, when I contacted the original question owner, he felt that my answer was correct.

Comment: In addition, thanks a lot for your other comments.

Comment: @KarthickS: Well the requirements state `If the number contains more than one of these attributes, print every word` so the spec is ambiguous at least.

Comment: Hi Chris, the original blog post owner has confirmed what you mentioned here. It is indeed a mistake. Thanks a lot for pointing it out.